# How can I make a Blockly custom block statement not editable

Tags: blockly

I have created this custom blocks that have 2 statement input (`PARAMS` & `CODE`):
[image]

Every green block is not `editable/movable/deletable` but I can still drag the pink block before `numero1`.

How can I prevent any block addition to the first statement (aka `PARAMS`)? I've tried this way without success

```
 <block deletable="false" editable="false">
      <statement name="PARAMS" editable="false"></statement>
      <statement name="CODE"></statement>
 </block>
```

Answer (score 1):

The block `editable` flag only prevents fields on the block from getting edited. It does not prevent connections from changing. Blocky currently doesn't support such a parameter.